# How do `default` and `default_if_none` behave if variable is missing or undefined?

Tags: django

In Django, how do [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#default) and [`default_if_none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#default) behave if the variable is missing from the request context?

For example, take this view:

```py
def example_view(request):
    return render(request, 'example.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
```

And take this corresponding Django template:

```html
{{ missing_variable|default:"default value" }}
<br>
{{ missing_variable|default_if_none:"default_if_none value" }}
```

What will be rendered here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` uses the fallback value if the variable is falsey or if it is missing:

```html
{{ missing_variable|default:"default value" }}
```

-> renders `default value`.

However, `default_if_none` only uses the fallback value if the variable exists and is `None`, it does not use the fallback value if the variable is missing from the request context:

```html
{{ missing_variable|default_if_none:"default_if_none value" }}
```

-> renders nothing.